# Is "I like [adjective]" acceptable in formal contexts?

Tags: formality, syntactic-analysis

Lately I've seen a lot this "I like [adjective]" structure. I really like this kind of "untranslatable" structures because those are the ones that make me feel I'm really speaking English (and not just a version of another language translated to English). Here are some examples to see what I mean:

- [This comment](https://www.instagram.com/p/9plk5Ds9In/) reads: Washington is moody... I like moody.
- [This book](https://books.google.es/books?id=bEDNCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=%22i+like+steady%22&source=bl&ots=nWZaUB3A-h&sig=vMVL5q7nOaD2qnGiTc73FFO1_8A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ04PH2PLJAhVJORQKHYAgA6UQ6AEIQjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22i%20like%20steady%22&f=false) reads: A: "Not too bad, just steady"; B: "I like steady"
- [This book](https://books.google.es/books?id=YZgPSyHULCkC&pg=PA430&lpg=PA430&dq=%22i+like+silly%22&source=bl&ots=d3aduPm8P4&sig=VIQ_N0KbEsbfcToLFiuywzzKA90&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB04jr2PLJAhVI8RQKHfZPD2Y4ChDoAQgpMAI#v=onepage&q=%22i%20like%20silly%22&f=false) states: It's a silly premise, but sometimes I like silly.
- [This book](https://books.google.es/books?id=2TQ7vdSIZ10C&pg=PT67&lpg=PT67&dq=%22i+like+silly%22&source=bl&ots=ztayVlqP79&sig=d4hijEG5cJ-bK10v9zPwDLPmssU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB04jr2PLJAhVI8RQKHfZPD2Y4ChDoAQgyMAU#v=onepage&q=%22i%20like%20silly%22&f=false) goes like: You are silly. I like silly.
- In a [chapter](http://www.tvfanatic.com/quotes/this-is-so-cheesy-yes-i-like-cheesy-me-too-yeah-i) from The office, Pam says: This is so cheesy. [...] I like cheesy.
- The headline of [this article](http://www.rpc.co.uk/index.php?option=com_easyblog&view=entry&id=149&Itemid=108) is: "I like risky"
- A comment from [this page](http://www.slashfilm.com/guardians-galaxy-2-story-marvel-thought-james-gunns-idea-sequel-risky/#comment-1839323905) is: "I like risky!"
- [This blog](http://wholesomemommy.com/easy-snowman-holiday-decor-or-giftable-in-30-minutes/) starts by saying: So I like easy.
- In [this page](http://www.dierickxglenn.com/2015/07/19/outfit-keep-it-classy/) you can read: I like classy very much.
- One of the comments in [this thread](http://www.datehookup.com/Thread-10599.htm) says: I like classy but I also like...

So my question is: is this structure used in formal speaking?

Note that I'm not interested in knowing how gramatical this is in the strictest sense of the word. What I want to know is whether I can use this structure without being considered too informal in situations when a minimum level of formality is required, or sholud I rather try and do without it in such contexts?

Secondarily, I've seen that the adjective doesn't generally stand completely alone, but it usually follows a sentence with a noun or pronoun (*moody* and *Washington*, *silly* and *premise*, *cheesy* and *this*...), but that's not always the case (*I like risky* or *I like easy*). Some have gone a step further and used the adjective as a subject: in the last page linked, someone says "I think classy makes a guy just as hot as trashy".

Can an adjective be used as a subject that way? If so, would such use be considered informal, or also formal?

Finally, I have also noticed all the adjectives end with "-y". Would the same thing apply to adjectives that don't end with "-y", like "nice", "careful", "fun" and such? Could you say: "He's nice. I like nice." or "She's careful. I like careful."?

Comment: This is a judgement call. After snowclones like 'X-adj is the new Y-adj' (eg 'Pre-owned Is the New New') and 'I don't do Z-adj' (eg 'I don't do sad'), this use of adjectives where nouns would be expected is certainly widespread. But I'd say that in all but a handful of cases, examples are non-standard to quite informal.

Comment: It seems to me that occasions for oral discourse that are too formal for this usage are becoming rarer. I could well imagine a President of the United States using this one and perhaps even in a State of the Union or inaugural address. Where would a modern Higgins take Eliza to settle his bet?

Comment: This is a beautifully written question! Your English is excellent, and your question could have been written by any intelligent, linguistically savvy, native English speaker. Well done. (I have up-voted both comments above.)

Comment: The thing that isn't "formal" is "like".  Your personal preferences are not generally to be injected into a formal speech or documents.   (But, as others have implied, how formal do you want to be?)

Comment: Define "*acceptable*". Define "*formal context*". Should be closed as unclear or primarily opinion-based.